# What amp value of residual current breaker and miniature breaker for pool heater

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, water-heater, pool

I am looking to install a heater for a swimming pool. Following the manufacturers specification with a 220-240 volt circuit the device draws 53 amps.
There is also a dedicated RCD safety circuit that must be connected to a 30mA RCD.

So what size of breaker (MCB) should I use, 50amp or 63amp? I am thinking 63amp to allow for the 80% of use rule.
So if it is 50/63 amp I would need 4mm copper cable?  A diagram in the manual states that 6mm cable is used within the device.

So if I use a 63amp breaker (MCB) do I need a 63amp RCD with 30mA?

[image: Table of amps drawn by device]

[image: wiring plan for RCD and MCB]

Comment: AWG10 is 5.3mm can hold 55A and need 50A breaker. AWG8 is 8.29mm can hold 66A and need 63A breaker. If You use 63A breaker on 6mm cable You can smoke it. Especially that this is heater cable. Check - that 53A is real power consumption or max allowed for cables before melting. if real consumption then think about something beter engineered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply what is AWG I am based in Europe. We had 2.5mm, 4mm, 6mm and 10mm wire gauges. All copper. So it looks like the 50amp MCB would be correct as the draw is 52amps and 6mm cable (looking at this chart 4mm/AWG 6 should be enough for  50 amps https://www.enerdrive.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Cable-Chart.pdf ) so 6mm is safe.

Comment: Where did your two images come from? I'd guess the bottom one is from the instructions. Is the top chart something random off the internet? If you post the brand/model of your heater, an electrician may be able to find the information that you're not seeing...

Comment: @Gurnard Im in EU too. Here we have bigger problem : ) - 6mm cable can be: Al/PVC-34A, Al/XLPE-45A, Cu/PVC-56A, CU/XLPE-64A. I like when cable is marked in AWG - know what is power limit without checking datasheet.  BTW. I do same RCD as breaker.

Comment: @k_z thanks for the response. The same RCD as breaker is good thanks.

Comment: @FreeMan Both images are from the manual. You can run the heater with 3 phase also so there is another chart for that but I am only running single phase. The power outputs in the first image are for the different models of heater.